# How do I detect when a user clicks on my slider rather than just sliding in unity?

Tags: c#, slider, unity-game-engine

I am using a Slider control to get feedback from a user in Unity. I know how to detect when the user changes the value of the slider when they slide the arrow.

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to detect if the user just clicks on the current position of the slider if they don't want to move it. I would like to avoid adding other visual controls.

Is there any way to detect when the user clicks on the slider?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use event trigger and select pointer Click and End Drag. 
I had the same problem and I solved that way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html

From there you could check if the value of the slider has changed or not to see if the user clicked on the current position.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;// Required when using Event data.

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler// required interface when using the OnPointerDown method.
{
    //Do this when the mouse is clicked over the selectable object this script is attached to.
    public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData eventData) 
    {
        Debug.Log (this.gameObject.name + " Was Clicked.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what the Op is looking for.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem wasn't in the code, I just needed to add a pointerClick event trigger.